# I am getting error in Shell Script Sub Menu Options Program

Tags: shell

I am making a **Sub Menu** user options kind of program and unable to understand why its not even working.
My effort code is :-

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Main Program
#
choice=10
option=10
while [$choice -ne 5]
do
    clear
    echo "------------------------------"
    echo "Main Menu"
    echo "------------------------------"
    echo "[1] FIle Utilities"
    echo "[2] Process Utilities"
    echo "[3] Alias Utilities"
    echo "[4] Envorinment Utilites"
    echo "[5] Exit"
    echo "------------------------------"
    read choice
    case $choice in
    1) clear
       while [$option -ne 4]
       do
       clear
       echo "------------------------------"
       echo "File Utilities"
       echo "------------------------------"
       echo "[1] Change File Permission"
       echo "[2] Move a File"
       echo "[3] Dump Dir"
       echo "[4] Return to Main Menu"
       echo "------------------------------"
       read option
       option=4;
       done;;
    2) clear
       option=10;
       while [$option -ne 3]
       do
       clear
       echo "------------------------------"
       echo "Process Utilities"
       echo "------------------------------"
       echo "[1] Dump Process"
       echo "[2] Kill Process"
       echo "[3] Return to Main Menu"
       echo "------------------------------"
       read option
       option=3;
       done;;
    3) clear
       option=10;
       while [$option -ne 3]
       do
       clear
       echo "------------------------------"
       echo "Alias Utilities"
       echo "------------------------------"
       echo "[1] Create Alias"
       echo "[2] Remove Alias"
       echo "[3] Return to Main Menu"
       echo "------------------------------"
       read option
       option=3;
       done;;
    4) clear
       option=10;
       while [$option -ne 3]
       do
       clear
       echo "------------------------------"
       echo "Environment Utilities"
       echo "------------------------------"
       echo "[1] Dump Environment"
       echo "[2] Modify Environment"
       echo "[3] Return to Main Menu"
       echo "------------------------------"
       read option
       option=3;
       done;;
    5) clear
       clear
       echo "------------------------------"
       echo "Program Exit"
       echo "------------------------------";;
    *) clear
       echo " Wrong Input Selected ";;
    esac
 done
```

What Error i am getting is:-
**./main: 7: ./main: [10: not found**

Please help me where i am doing wrong....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here:

```
while [$choice -ne 5]
```

`[` is a program, not mere syntax. (at a prompt, type `type [` and `help [`)

Like any program, the shell requires a space between it and its arguments.

```
while [ $choice -ne 5 ]
```

Comment: Also, use the shell's `select` statement to save yourself a lot of work. Should be lots of examples of `select` on stackoverflow